# Show only one item per row in UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, uicollectionview

I don't have code as I don't know how to begin with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not try something to start with and if you get stuck, come back and bring the code?

Comment: How about `UITableView`?

Answer (score 2):

As of [Apples WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766) concerning `UICollectionViews` you should create a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
As said there you should set the bottom and top Edge Insets of the CollectionView so that only one Cell will fit in between and the rest will be done by the CollectionView.

The Edge Insets can be done with `UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`

So, in your Layout you can customize the `init` like this:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

        CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat spacing = bounds.size.height / 2 - self.itemSize.height / 2;
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(spacing, 0, spacing, 0);
    }
    return self;
}
```

So that, in fact you make the height of the CollectionView the height of the Screen minus the height of a cell, except that it's centered.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If want one item why you don`t try UItableView

```
UITableView *myTableView = [UITableView alloc] init];
```

Delegate

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```